# Need help styling react-native-elements input component

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styling, react-native-elements

I am trying to figure out how I would style an input using react-native-elements like the picture shown in the docs... I want the inputs to look like the top ones with the white background, but I have no idea how I would go about doing this. The main issue I am stuck with is getting the pointy edges on the input container. Any help? [image: This picture]
<sub>(source: [github.io](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/img/input.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to make this, but I think `ImageBackground` can solve the problem. I used it as a picture of a question because I don't have an `image`.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,TextInput,ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Use ImageBackground
        </Text>
        <ImageBackground style={{height: 40 , width:"100%"}} source={require("./test.png")}>
        <TextInput style={{height: 40,color:"red",paddingHorizontal:120}} />
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

[image]